# Linux - Formating subject and words in an email using mutt

Tags: linux, bash, automation, sh, mutt

I'm having some trouble to learn Linux and do some simple tasks, like the following:

I'm using MUTT to send an email with an attachment, but i need to format the text inside the email and in the subject.
How can i make "ç", "ã" and spaces between lines? In portuguese we use them a lot.

Follows what i've got until now as an example:

```
echo "Friends, (Two spaces to the next line) ã ç " |/usr/bin/mutt -s "Subject - ã and ç needed" -a /home/cvna/ZELDA/example.txt -- cvfilho@timbrasil.com.br
```

If possible, could anyone post ways to advanced formatting like choosing kind of font, italic and so on?

Thanks!

Comment: I would use a programming language (for example Python or maybe Perl, or maybe Java) and create a small program which would take all required parameters including message text and format it into a proper MIME message, w/ an alternate HTML part and so on. Mutt is more suitable for interactive usage

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. This question should go to http://superuser.com/ instead, since it is not about programming. That said, keep in mind that mutt is a text mail client, and as such does not do italics etc. If your terminal is set up correctly, ç and ã should be no problem though.

Answer (score 2):

Use a here document:

```
/usr/bin/mutt -s "Subject - ã and ç needed" -a /home/cvna/ZELDA/example.txt -- cvfilho@timbrasil.com.br <<EOF
Friends,

ã ç
EOF
```

For the two letters, if your locale (`LANG=pt_PT.utf8`) is set correctly and your terminal can understand UTF-8, you should just be able to type them normally.

Comment: On the email field it functioned, but my subject came in blank. How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure; I can't see any reason why the subject would be blank.